# How to return a Tensor type or an IndexedSlices type via tf.cond()?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use the origin sparse tensor (`tf.IndexedSlices` type) when pct < 0.75, otherwise use a dense tensor (`tf.Tensor` type, created by `tf.convert_to_tensor`). Here is the code

```
def fn1():
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(sparse_gradient)
def fn2():
    return sparse_gradient

final_gradient = tf.cond(tf.less(pct, tf.constant(value=0.75, dtype=tf.float64)), fn1, fn2)
```

However, `tf.cond` need `fn1()` and `fn2()` have same return type, so this code will throw an Error:

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.
```

How can I fix this?  The control flow is a part of the Calculate graph, so I have to use `tf.cond`. Is there any other way to work it out?

Comment: what does sparse_gradient look like?

Comment: It is an instance of tf.IndexedSlice type. the gradient of embedding_lookup op is the type.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is impossible in static graph mode.(Eager mode may not have this problem) Because the type will be determined after graph's compiling. So we can not use different type by the runtime tensor value.
We can also find that in merge function, which is a base op of tensorflow's control flow:

```
def merge(inputs, name=None):

"""
...
This op handles both `Tensor`s and `IndexedSlices`. If inputs has a mix of
`Tensor`s and `IndexedSlices`, all inputs are converted to IndexedSlices
before merging.
...
"""
```